# MYSQL/PHP insert date

Tags: php, mysql

hi guys can i insert this

```
date_default_timezone_set(Asia/Hong_Kong);
$date = date('"m/d/Y H:i:s"');
```

instead of

```
"INSERT INTO date_time(`submitted_time`) VALUES (NOW())"
```

because my problem is using `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` gives me a inaccurate time

im doing this but when i look at the database this is what is been inserted `0000-00-00 00:00:00.0`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $date = date('"m/d/Y H:i:s"');
        $query = "INSERT INTO `date_time`(`submitted_time`)
                    VALUES('$date')";
        if($conn->query($query)) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
}
```

Comment: $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: yes when using NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() it shows what its 7 hours late

Comment: Where is your server? Is it located in a timezone that is 7 hours late?

Comment: make sure you are on the right time zone too

Comment: thats what i write but when inserting to db its just shows `0000-00-00 00:00:00.0`

Comment: yes im setting the timezone

Comment: confirm that the date time is a timestamp/date field in your database

Comment: @PhpDev its in `current_timestamp` as its data type

Comment: try this: SYSDATE()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want to insert a datetime that you generate this is how it is done.

NOTE: The format of a date must be `Y-m-d H:i:s` as that is the format MYSQL understands for its DateTime data type

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO `date_time` (`submitted_time`) VALUES(?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    // note the DateTime must be in this format to store correctly on a MYSQL database
    $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $dt);
    $status = $stmt->execute();

    if(!$status) {
        echo $stmt->error;    
        exit;
    }
    echo "success";
}
```

If you want to view, show your users a DateTime in any other format that is the job of the presentation layer to reformat it to whichever locale specific format.

> Your script **was** at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
>   [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: getting this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Sorry little typo. Fixed preceeding line needed a `;` Like `echo $stmt->error;   `

Comment: Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference and this shows but it work btw. thanks a lot

Comment: and may i ask, what syntax is this? is it PDO?

Comment: No its `MYSQLI_` unless I made another typo

Comment: how can i remove the notice?

Comment: `$status = $stmt->execute();`

Comment: im sorry. its in this line `   $stmt->bind_param('s', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));`

Comment: Yea thats the line I changed

Comment: works perfectly can you please answer this so i can fully understand the code. how come the values is ? `VALUES(?)`

Comment: Its all to do with protecting yourself from SQL Injection. See additional yellow note